# Apply same options to multiple `addplot` in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Can I apply the same options to all `addplot`'s in a single `axis` environment in `pgfplots`?

For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}
     \addplot[%plot 1
              color = red,
              mark = none
             ] {x^2 - x +4};
     \addplot[%same options as in plot 1
             ] {x^3};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Supply the options to `axis` environment instead which will make (most but not all of) the options valid for all `\addplot` commands.

Comment: I tried it but it caused the axes to disappear. I'm using the decorations library to add an arrow on the curve, which might be causing the problem.

Comment: Probably you are not using `postaction`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a style (or more):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{style_a}=[color = red, mark = none, dashed]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        ymin=-10,
        ymax=10]
     \addplot[style_a] {x^2};
     \addplot[style_a] {x^3 -4};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just for future readers: at the time of writing this answer `tikzstyle` is deprecated. From the documentation

> Starting with pgfplots 1.1, `\tikzstyle` should no longer be used to set `pgfplots` options.
>   Although `\tikzstyle` is still supported for some older `pgfplots` options, you should replace any occurrence of `\tikzstyle` with `\pgfplotsset{<style name>/.style={<key-value-list>}}` or the associated
>   `/.append style` variant

With this in mind

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{style a/.style={color = red, mark = none, dashed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        ymin=-10,
        ymax=10]
     \addplot[style a] {x^2};
     \addplot[style a] {x^3 -4};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want some keys for all addplots, you do not need to define a named style and recall it. 
Just say `every axis plot/.append style={....}`

(Because `every axis plot={....}` seems to be not enough in some cases.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-10,  xmax=10,
ymin=-10,  ymax=10,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
every axis plot/.append style={red, mark=none, dashed},
]
\addplot[] {x^2};
\addplot[] {x^3 -4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is `every axis plot/.style={....}` for setting a style and `every axis plot/.append style` to append to it.

Comment: Yes, I know (?).

Comment: You write "Because `every axis plot={....}` seems to be not enough in some cases.". I do not think it will ever work. That is why I wrote my comment.

Comment: Ah ok, I have an example at mine and `every axis plot={....}` was enough.